# IOS Application loader shows bundle error, with armv7s and armv7

Tags: ios, binary, uploading, armv7

I have already waste 3 days "solving" this problem (actually I have tried everything i could imagine but get nothing).

While binary uploading of my application i get the following error: ERROR ITMS-9000: "this bundle is invalid. armv7s are required to include armv7 architecture." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage).

I have read, that i have to unplug my iphone. Should i do that while binary uploading, or when?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your project & target settings screen from Xcode showing the "Architectures" and "Valid Architectures" settings?

Comment: Here they are: [link]https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-HhLot2PGbtbEZjXzJ4LWRvMkk/edit?usp=sharing[/link]

Comment: are you uploading your Release or Debug target?

Comment: try to upload release version of my app

Comment: are you including any libraries or Frameworks (e.g. open source ones) outside of the iOS SDK?

Comment: StoreKit, MediaPlayer, UIKit, Foundation, CoreGraphics. Also tried to add facebook sdk, but decided to do that later...

Comment: so what am i do not right?

Answer (score 0):

Select Project Name Blue icon:

In Build Settings Search for 'arch'
Make sure that you've included armv7 in your release code. You have to open the two areas and make sure that armv7 is typed into either Valid Architecture or Architectures. The architecture used is a union of both settings so just be sure that armv7 is in one or the other section.

BTW - For help with other validation issues see this [technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2318/_index.html) from Apple.

[image: Armv7 Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

1.Unconnect iOS device from your Mac, 
2. Dont select any simulator, just leave it as it is, iOS device option
3. Archive it
4. publish it